Unable to run notebooks on GPU (on-premises), running kubeflow on ranchers k3s cluster
I have installed kubeflow on k3s cluster.
I have configured the cluster to be able to access GPUs and it's working fine for test pods on gpu, and I can see nvidia-smi output on pods.
But, I want notebooks created from kubeflow dashboard to run on gpus, I am not able to find anything how I can do this. I have selected gpus from UI in notebook creation on dashboard but still while running jupyter notebook following command returns false:
torch.cuda.is_avaiable() return False
For k3s, we need to add "runtimeClassName: nvidia" in pod specs but there is not way I can do this in kubeflow manifests.
Please suggest me something or guide me if I am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

i solved this issue by setting nvidia to be the default runtime. run it in your local machine with gpu:
sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=containerd --nvidia-set-as-default
sudo systemctl restart containerd
sudo systemctl status containerd
